# Procedure não retorna os dados do select

Tags: sql-server

Criei uma procedure simples, ela recebe um parâmetro e deveria retornar os dados de acordo com esse parâmetro:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[testeLike]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @teste varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    select * from teste
        where valor like '@teste%'
END
```

executando a proc:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

não retornou nenhum dado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas se eu pego o código do select e o testo, os dados são retornados:

```
select * from teste
        where valor like 'tes%'
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

não consigo compreender qual é o problema. No parâmetro já tentei passar com aspas simples, mas deu na mesma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri o problema. Estava na hora de passar o parâmetro no select, o correto é assim:

```
select * from Produto
        where nome like @teste+'%'
```